# How to generate an Ethereum "brain wallet" in Javascript?

Tags: web3js, addresses, javascript, private-key, brain-wallets

Namely, enter string -> get private key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer by [Vitalik Buterin on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/535ovp/is_there_a_javascript_library_for_generating/d7q8hq7):

> Try:
>
> ```
> function brainwallet(username, password, hardness) {
>     return web3.sha3(Array(hardness + 1).join(username + ":" + password));
> }
> ```
>
> Set `hardness` to something reasonably large, at least 2000. Use your
>   usual username for `username`, even if lots of people know it. These
>   two things together give you a ~20 bit-of-entropy improvement in
>   security over the simple "sha3 of your string" approach at basically
>   no cost to hardness of memorization.

Comment: where is the js library to access this?

Comment: @duckx https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/